# how to obtain the number of classes using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

`img_height,img_width=180,100 batch_size=32 train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir1,validation_split=0.01,subset="training",seed=123,image_size=(img_height, img_width),batch_size=batch_size)`

Output: Found 1376 files belonging to 4 classes.
Using 1363 files for training.

how can I get the total number of classes in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like

```
train_gen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(etc
```

then you can use the code below to get the type of information you want

```
classes=list(train_gen.class_indices.keys())
class_indices=list(train_gen.class_indices.values())
num_of_classes=len(classes)
```

train_gen.class_indices is a dictionary of the form {class: index}

Answer (score 0):

`label_map = (train.ds.class_indices)`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.